# Word for matrices with following property

Tags: matrices, terminology, matrix-equations

Suppose I have two matrices $A$ and $B$ and they satisfy the property that:

$A$ has non-zero values on row $j$ $\implies$ Row $j$ of $B$ contains only zero values.

$B$ has non-zero values on row $j$ $\implies$ Row $j$ of $A$ contains only zero values.

Is there a word for this relationship? Like, can I say they are some sort of "Orthogonal"?

Comment: There is no such word that I know of. How did this property come up? If you tell us where you came across it, we might have a better idea of where to look for such a term

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any such name either. But if you want a word to define and then use for a paper/problem you are writing up (i.e. a *nonce* word), I'd recommend describing them as **complementary**, rather than orthogonal.